# How can I post to the wall of a Facebook Fan Page using PHP and Open Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sample code is appreciated, I can't seem to find any simple examples of this online.

Comment: I wrote an article about this recently. You need to get extended_access permission and essentially post as an authenticated user that is an admin of the page. http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/permanent-facebook-sessions-and-posting-as-a-page

Answer (score 3):

Using the new [Facebook PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), it's very easy to accomplish this.

Requirements:

1. [Extended Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), depending on your needs
2. Page ID

Now as I said, depending on your requirements you may need `offline_access`, `manage_pages`, but for now this is the simplest straight forward way of doing this:

After downloading the PHP SDK, and in the `example.php` file:

- Acquire the `publish_stream` permission:

  ```
  <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
  ```
- After successful authentication, you post to the page wall the same way you do it for normal [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) profile (and with the same options too, `message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source`):

  ```
  $page_id = '123456789';
  $feed_array = array(
      'message' => "Hello world!"
  );
  $page_post = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$feed_array);
  ```

Result:
[image]

*Please note that this approach requires you being an administrator of the page.*

Comment: This is using the Graph API not the Open Graph.

Comment: Many people can have different roles on a page, what roles are allowed to give an app the permission to manage the facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

in this change the /me/feed/ to your page id, I did't try....Just check

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'some meesgae',
        'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
        'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
        'link' => 'mylink.com',
        'description' => 'this is a description',
        'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search', 'link' => 'google.com')) );
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $attachment);
```

Comment: Where do you get `$access_token` from?