# Manage Facebook Pages

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook account with multiple pages.I want to manage these pages from my website.
1)change images of each page
2)Add comments to wall of each page.

is it possible to use facebook API.Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Companion.

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729941/how-can-i-post-to-the-wall-of-a-facebook-fan-page-using-php-and-open-graph-api/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can manage the pages from your website.

What you to do?

Use login with FACEBOOK API + You need to create an application using FACEBOOK API.

Comment: could u please more clear, is possible to do it from my own website or i want create a facebook app?

Comment: There are different approaches.

Comment: 1) Using like block. In this you can see the page only but you can not manage the page. 2) Use login with face book, but i am not sure you can do manage it. 3) App can do this work. You can manage your pages easily.