# Post to Facebook page using php

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a script to post to facebook but I'm having problems with how the data is posted on facebook.

Since it may help others here is the full code

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = 0;

$pageId   = "XXXXXXXX";
$permSess = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    "appId" => "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "secret" => "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "cookie" => true
));

$page = $facebook->api("/{$pageId}");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    
    <head>
        <title>Post to Page Wall</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        />
        <meta name="description" content="Post to page's wall" />
        <style>
            body {
                font-family:'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }
            h1 a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #3b5998;
            }
            h1 a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            form {
                border: 1px solid #eee;
                padding: 20px;
                width: 550px;
            }
            textarea, select, input, label {
                width: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                height: 20px;
                clear: both;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            textarea {
                height: 100px;
            }
            label {
                border: none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            input#submit {
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Post to Friend's Wall</h1>
        <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'submit'])) { $link=$
        _POST[ 'link']; $message=$ _POST[ 'message']; $attachment=a rray($message,$link
        ); $rest=$ facebook->api(array( "uid" => $pageId, "method" => "stream.publish", "access_token"
            => $permSess, "message" => $message )); } ?>
            <form id="Wall" name="Wall"
            method="post">
                <label for="URL">URL:</label>
                <input id="link" name="link">
                <label for="Message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send!">
            </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem:

I was using an example posted [here](http://bobbelderbos.com/2011/08/example-facebook-php-sdk-post-to-friends-wall/) and using that example the links submitted on the URL field where getting posted on facebook just like if you do it yourself (with the image and the description of the site) but using my code I can't make it happen in the same way.

On " [How can I post to the wall of a Facebook Fan Page using PHP and Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729941/how-can-i-post-to-the-wall-of-a-facebook-fan-page-using-php-and-open-graph-api) " some user had posted an answer but don't work in my case.

The difference between my code and the code on the other site is the "$attachment" part of the code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sendTo  = $_POST['friend'];
    $link    = $_POST['link'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    // all options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile
    $attachment = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'link' => $link
    );
    
    if ($result = $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed/", 'post', $attachment)) {
        $feedbackMessage = "Message sent to friend $sendTo";
    } else {
        $feedbackMessage = "Oops something went wrong";
    }
}
?>
```

So... the question is how to properly post to a Facebook page without loss any of the benefits or the formatting using my script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the changed code in an answer below instead of changing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will let you post to the facebook page and keep the format, I got What you mean !

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $link = $_POST['link'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];



$attachment = array(
        'access_token' => $permSess,
        'message' => $message,
        'link' => $link

    );
if(    $result = $facebook->api(
        "/".$pageId."/links",
        'post',
        $attachment
    )){
                $feedbackMessage = "Message sent to friend $sendTo";
            } else {
                $feedbackMessage = "Oops something went wrong";
            } 

}
?>
```