# Upload Post to Facebook Automatically in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I've made my own "blog-style" site, without using WordPress or anything of the sort. I'm looking for a way to automatically post a certain portion of the article to the Facebook Wall of the Facebook Page I run for the website. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm using PHP for post submission.

Comment: Have you tried to read [facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com)?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729941/how-can-i-post-to-the-wall-of-a-facebook-fan-page-using-php-and-open-graph-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the Facebook API.  You can probably find PHP libraries that cover much of the functionality but it would still be a good idea to get your head around the Facebook API so that you understand how things work.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/